# Concatenating two sparse matrices using sparse package in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two sparse matrices in pythons sparse package. See below:

```
import sparse
total_coords1 = [(0,1,1,2), (0,0,2,3), (0,1,2,2)]
data1 = [1,1,1,1]
s1 = sparse.COO(total_coords1, data1, shape=(7, 5, 12))

total_coords2 = [(0,1,2,3), (0,1,1,2), (0,1,2,2)]
data2 = [2,2,2,2]
s2 = sparse.COO(total_coords1, data1, shape=(7, 5, 15))
```

I want to combine these two sparse matrices into a single sparse matrix along the last axis (axis=2). something like:

```
s3 = sparse.COO(s1, s2)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you aren't using the `scipy.sparse` package, but rather the `pydata` alternative (or extension).

Comment: For future reference, the API for this `sparse` package: https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/sparse.html

Comment: Yes that's right. Thanks, that API be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not mention the axis along which you want to concatenate, I will assume axis=2, as it is the only possible axis along which we can concatenate the given arrays.

You can use [`concatenate`](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/sparse.concatenate.html) function to get a single sparse matrix of shape (7, 5, 27):

```
s3 = sparse.concatenate([s1,s2], axis=2)
```